# How can I disable Mail and only use Outlook 365 for my Outlook.com account?

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook

When I set up this new laptop I synced my Outlook.com account and added it to Mail. I now have Office365 through my employer and have added my Outlook.com account to Outlook proper. However, whenever I receive an email @outlook.com I get notifications from Mail.

Can I remove my account from Mail without removing it from Windows 10? Can I nuke Mail altogether?

Comment: "Can I nuke Mail altogether?" - While it is possible I don't suggest you do this.  I suggest just disconnecting/disassociating your account with Mail and then changing the default email program to Outlook instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove your email account from Windows 10 Mail app, you need to use Settings -> Manage Accounts -> select account -> Delete account.

More details on Microsoft Support website: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Delete-an-email-account-from-Mail-and-Calendar-apps-dba65c49-648d-4d76-9f88-b7bc22a2cc3d